# Where should i place the route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this controller:

```
 public function watchlist(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $id=$request->id;
            if($id)
            {
                $add=new Watchlist();
                $add->product_id=$id;

                if(!Auth::check())
                {            
                    echo json_encode(FALSE);die;                        
                }

                $add->user_id=Auth::user()->id;      
                $add->save();        
                echo json_encode(TRUE);die;
            }

            echo json_encode(FALSE);die;
        }
    }
```

and the route is:

```
Route::post('/product/watchlist', 'ProductController@watchlist');
```

where should i place this route?
If i place this route under auth and web middleware group i got

> token mismatch exception.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/product/addform', 'ProductController@addform');    
    Route::post('/product/add', 'ProductController@add');

   Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        Route::get('/','ProductController@index');  
        Route::get('/product','ProductController@index');               
        Route::post('/product/watchlist', 'ProductController@watchlist'); //here
    });
});
```

if i put it outside of web and auth middleware group

> i couldnot get id of the user i need.

And if i put it under new auth middleware group outside web middleware group

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
                 Route::post('/product/watchlist', 'ProductController@watchlist');
    )};
```

i got

> Unauthorized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're making use of **user's session** in your controller, for sure your route should be put under the **web** middleware so that user session is handled correctly.

However, in order for it to work, you'll need to make sure that you pass the **XSRF token** along with your AJAX request. You'll find the token in **XSRF-TOKEN** cookie that Laravel creates. You'll need to pass it in **X-XSRF-TOKEN** header of your request.

Regarding **auth** middleware, you should add that to the request only for requests that require user to be authenticated.

Comment: passing the XSRF token along with your AJAX request. any link explaining this?

Comment: It depends on what you use to send requests to the backend

Comment: @yash Chaudhary laravel 5.2 it is.

Comment: Ok.  got it..` data: {
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        "id": id
        }` is what i needed.